# Será problema de escopo?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Estou com um problema na obtenção do valor de uma variável em NodeJs.

```js
router.post('/admin/categorias/nova', (req, res) => {

  var erro = [];

  Categoria.findOne({
    slug: req.body.slug
  }).then((categorias) => {
    if (categorias) {
      erro.push({texto: "Slug Existente tente uma nova"});
    }
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('Erro na verificação de Slugs existentes: ' + err);
  });

  if (erro.length > 0) {
    res.render('admin/addcategorias', {erro: erro});
  } else {};
});
```

Como podem observar, tanto a variável erro, como a função para consulta no banco de dados, "Categoria.findOne", estão dentro de uma rota. Eu declaro a variável fora da função Categoria, a preencho dentro da função, para só após, verificá-la ela em uma condicional. Dentro da função ela retorna length = 1 (quando entra na condição), porém fora da função ela continua com valor 0. O que pode ser?

Comment: JS á assíncrono, talvez esse seja o seu problema, quando você tenta utilizar a variável fora da rota, a mesma ainda não teve seu valor setado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada ás perguntas que marquei como duplicadas. Na prática o teu `if (erro.length > 0) {` tem de estar dentro do `.then(`